# Vue.js reactivity inner mechanisms

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, reactive-programming

Given the following Vue code, how does it know to render the `v-for` again when `selected` is changed?

It makes complete sense to me when `todos` is changed.

So, Vue notices that there's a method `isSelected` involved and then uses "reflection" to watch the `selected` value, since it's an instance value?

Is that what's happening under the hood?

```html
<div id="app">
   <ol>
     <li v-for="todo in todos" :class="{ 'selected': isSelected(todo.text) }">
  {{ todo.text }}
     </li>
   </ol>
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        todos: [
            { text: 'foo' },
            { text: 'bar' },
            { text: 'quz' }
         ],
         'selected': 'bar'
    },
    methods: {
        isSelected: function(text) {
           return text != this.selected;
        }
    }
})

app.todos.push({ text: 'test' });
app.todos[0].text = 'change';
app.selected = 'foo';
</script>
```

Comment: Vue uses a system based around modified getters and setters (`get`, `set`)

Comment: What is reactivity and what constitutes reflection in JavaScript?

Comment: @Vivick, I get that :) Just wondering how Vue detects that it needs to render again when the `selected` value changes...

Comment: @AluanHaddad, "reflection" was an assumption :) By reactivity I mean how Vue knows how to render again when the `selected` value changes, since it's way down in the `isSelected` method...

Comment: I see. I was trying to be provocative. I don't think that qualifies as reactivity unless we concede that all databinding systems exhibit reactivity (that would be an OK conclusion actually). As for reflection, JavaScript is inherently reflective (with every property access)..

Comment: @AluanHaddad, tnx for your feedback, but can you explain how exactly Vue knows to trigger the render again when the selected value changes ;p It's not straightforward, now is it?

Comment: Vue replaces the properties with getters and setters and when such setters are called, Vue, besides setting the values, notifies all observers that depend on that value (such as the template or other computed properties). Is this what you want to know?